# Can a 64 bit dll be loaded on a 32 bit JVM?

Tags: dll, 64-bit, jvm

I have a 64 bit dll that has got dependancy with 64 bit oracle and built on a 64 bit machine with 64 bit JVM.
Can this dll be used in a 64 bit system having 32 bit oracle ? JVM is 64 bit.
Also can we load a 64 bit dll using 32 bit JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process. Nor does it work the other way around. See [this article](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/04/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-6/) for details.

Comment: I added a link to a blog article explaining the topic in detail.

Comment: Thanx a lot, You are a saviour